# Need to convert a SQL Server xml blob into a table for manipulation

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a table that has xml content stored as a string (this was all put together before xml data types).  Here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfLibAddress xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <libAddress Address="11" Type="User" />
  <libAddress Address="79" Type="User" />
  <libAddress Address="18" Type="UserGroup" />
  <libAddress Address="19" Type="UserGroup" />
  <libAddress Address="5" Type="MailGroup" />
  <libAddress Address="7" Type="MailGroup" />
  <libAddress Address="someone@somewhere.com" Type="EmailAddress" />
  <libAddress Address="someoneelse@somewhere.com" Type="EmailAddress" />
</ArrayOfLibAddress>
```

What I need is a T-SQL statement that will return the following:

```
Address                     Type
11                          User
79                          User
18                          UserGroup
19                          UserGroup
5                           MailGroup
7                           MailGroup
someone@somewhere.com       EmailAddress
someoneelse@somewhere.com   EmailAddress
```

For instance, if this value is loaded into a variable:

```
DECLARE @x xml = '{the xml content above}'
```

Then how do I turn this into a table?

I've found examples that will let me pull a single value out for an element that has an attribute that matches a certain value, but I can't find an example that shows how to turn the attribute values for all of the elements in the document into a tabular result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `nodes` to query over a xml variable :

```sql
SELECT
  T.addresses.value('./@Address', 'nvarchar(max)') [Address],  
  T.addresses.value('./@Type', 'nvarchar(max)') [Type]
FROM
  @x.nodes('//libAddress') T(addresses)
```

See [nodes() Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) on MSDN for more information